# I have Multiple Local Repos on Git, but I want to only work with one

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am still figuring out the basics with Git and using GitHub as my online repository. So while I was trying to teach myself and figure out everything, I guess I might of went crazy with the installing of different versions of Git Bash, Git GUI, Git Windows, Git Extensions, but the one I primarily use is Git Bash.

I must of went crazy with the "git init" command, because I have a ton of files showing up when I do a "git status." I am also tracking multiple repos, but I just want to be working with only one at a time. So my question, finally, is how do I resolve these conflicts and only work with one .git at a time through Git bash on my local machine?

This is what currently shows up when I do a "git status"

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 1 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#       modified:   ../../../GitHub/GitHelloWorld (new commits)
#       modified:   ../../../GitHub/StopFoodWaste (new commits, modified content
)
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../../../../.RubyMine40/
#       ../../../../.android/
#       ../../../../.appletviewer
#       ../../../../.asadminpass
#       ../../../../.bash_history
#       ../../../../.gem/
#       ../../../../.gitconfig
#       ../../../../.gitignore
#       ../../../../.kdiff3rc
#       ../../../../.m2/
#       ../../../../.ssh/
#       ../../../../AppData/
#       ../../../../Contacts/
#       ../../../../Desktop/
#       ../../../../DiskScrP.txt
#       ../../../AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf
#       ../../../Amazon MP3/
#       ../../../Battlefield 3/
#       ../../../BinaryTreeADT.class
#       ../../../BinaryTreeADT.java
#       ../../../CyberLink/
#       ../../../DataStrucNotes.docx
#       ../../../Dimitrios Arethas.docx
#       ../../../Dimitrios_Arethas_resume.rtf
#       ../../../Dimitrios_Arethas_resume_doc.docx
#       ../../../Expression/
#       ../../../Fiddler2/
#       ../../../German Reporter.m4v
#       ../../../GoogleCodeJam.class
#       ../../../GoogleCodeJam.java
#       ../../../Greatwide_cover.docx
#       ../../../IISExpress/
#       ../../../ITCS2175/
#       ../../../ITCS2214/
#       ../../../ITCS3200 Notes.docx
#       ../../../ITIS - Ethics/
#       ../../../Music/
#       ../../../My Kindle Content/
#       ../../../My Shapes/
#       ../../../My Web Sites/
#       ../../../Notes/
#       ../../../ProjectEuler.class
#       ../../../ProjectEuler.java
#       ../../../SQL Learn/
#       ../../../SQL Server Management Studio/
#       ../../../SaaS Class/
#       ../../../SharpDevelop Projects/
#       ../../../Visual Studio 11/
#       ../../../Visual Studio 2005/
#       ../../../Visual Studio 2008/
#       ../../
#       ../../../Youcam/
#       ../../../dativ_prepositions.docx
#       ../../../desktop.ini
#       ../../../dimitrios_engagement_checklist.doc
#       ../../../dimitrios_trial_schedule.doc
#       ../../../eclipse/
#       ../../../gitscc.config
#       ../../../me.jpg
#       ../../../workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE/
#       ../../../../Downloads/
#       ../../../../Dropbox/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the remote side, you can view your remotes repo with [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote -v
```

And remove the ones you don't want with

```
git remote rm name
```

See "[Working with Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)".

On the status side, try to find all `.git` directories you have.
You should be in a `GitHub/yourRepo` directory instead of having a `.git` almost at your `C:\` here.

Comment: Ok thanks I am trying it out now. Yeah that is my entire Documents folder